# Java JFrame class cannot be viewed

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I created a new JFrame class in java and added GUI elements and provided action functionality 
to these buttons.When I open later I cannot view the JFrame class I created, instead it is like a 
notepad File.Help me solve this!!!

Comment: Well a .java file _is_ a plain text file what do you expect. Please add more context to your question for a more serious answer. Like how you are trying to open the file; if you're using an IDE. All the things that will help paint a clearer picture for us to understand.

Answer (score 0):

frames in java usually set to not being visible , you have to change this setting , to do so you have to set in visible in your main function.

should be like this

```
public static void main (strings[] args) { 
frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem